# Installing Plotmtv

Tags: command-line, packaging

I'd like to install plotmtv. For this reason I used simply the command

```
sudo apt-get install plotmtv
```

but I get an error message saying that the package is missing, it is not available or it is inside another source.

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: If the answer below helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plotmtv` isn't in the repositories since Intrepid. But you could use a deb package. I was able to successfully install it in Vivid.

- 64-bit

  ```
  cd;
  wget https://launchpad.net/~hkroeger/+archive/ubuntu/engineeringoss/+files/plotmtv_1.4.1-R10%7E8527892_amd64.deb
  sudo dpkg -i plotmtv_1.4.1-R10\~8527892_amd64.deb
  ```
- 32-bit

  ```
  cd;
  wget https://launchpad.net/~hkroeger/+archive/ubuntu/engineeringoss/+files/plotmtv_1.4.1-R10%7E8527892_i386.deb
  sudo dpkg -i plotmtv_1.4.1-R10\~8527892_i386.deb
  ```

---

Check the installation

`apt-cache policy plotmtv`

```
plotmtv:
      Installed: 1.4.1-R10~8527892
      Candidate: 1.4.1-R10~8527892
      Version table:
     *** 1.4.1-R10~8527892 0
            100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```